# How can i change a text of a button without changing it's icon

Tags: javascript, html, button, icons, materialize

i have a "Pause" button with a pause_circle_outline materialize icon, and when it clicked i want to change the text to "Resume" and changing the icon to play_circle_outline, but when i try to change the text it changed the text and deletes the icon. here is my code snippet example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  
  $(document.getElementById("pause_btn")).click(function(){
      document.getElementById("pause_btn").innerText = "Resume"
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "Sources/js/select_require.js"></script>
    <script src = "Sources/js/routes.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <body>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="pause_btn">Pause<i class="material-icons right">pause_circle_outline</i></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.innerText` is a sort of "safe"* way to access a node's `innerHTML`, which in your case includes both the `Pause`-text, as well as the `<i.../>` tag.

A way to solve this is to add a `span` to hold the text. `span`s don't *do* anything (as they are inline elements and are by default formatted/shown as a simple text element), but they help by making the text node selectable by `document.querySelector`!

Example:

```js
var playing = true

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.querySelector("#pause_btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
      playing = !playing
      if(playing) {
        document.querySelector("#pause_btn span").innerText = "Pause"
        document.querySelector("#pause_btn i").innerText = "pause_circle_outline"
      } else {
        document.querySelector("#pause_btn span").innerText = "Resume"
        document.querySelector("#pause_btn i").innerText = "play_circle_outline"
      }
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <body>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="pause_btn">
      <span>Pause</span>
      <i class="material-icons right">pause_circle_outline</i>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also added some extra code to make it clickable multiple times!

---

*: By safe, in this context, I mean that it's safe from a security issue called [XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/). Generally it's better to use `innerText` when you don't explicitly *need* to change the HTML itself, but if you do: Make sure that there's **NO** way a user can input something that gets put into the `innerHTML`. What I initially meant was simply that writing to either `innerHTML` and `innerText` will always overwrite whatever contents the element has, and that `innerText` is generally the safer of the two.

Comment: when i do it on an empty project it works, but when i add it to my project it raises an error saying Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')

Comment: It's probable that the querySelector doesn't find anything! Check that your id is identical, or change what id you put in your querySelector.

Comment: this answer is incorrect and lacks explanation as to reasoning.

Comment: Which part is incorrect, @BenS?

Comment: Your definition of `innerText` being a safe way to access `innerHTML`. The former gets the text content the latter gets/sets the HTML/XML markup.

Furthermore, you are mixing and matching jQuery and Vanilla JS.

When using the former you don't need to use the standard Browser APIs.
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/ 

Last but not least, `span` is an inline element and can be used, for example to group other elements for styling. It has a purpose so it does sg.

I think it's better to help @avico34 understand the reasons than giving an opinionated solution.

Comment: @BenS Those are good points, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Both textContent and innerText remove child nodes when altered

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext)

Perhaps place your text within a `span` with an ID and change its `textContent`?

that way your `i` tag should remain untouched.

Comment: Maybe using innerHTML?

document.getElementById("pause_btn").innerHTML = 'Resume<i class="material-icons right">play_circle_outline</i>'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the icon along with the text to the innerHTML?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  
  $(document.getElementById("pause_btn")).click(function(){
      document.getElementById("pause_btn").innerHTML = 'Resume<i class="material-icons right">pause_circle_outline</i>'
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "Sources/js/select_require.js"></script>
    <script src = "Sources/js/routes.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <body>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="pause_btn">Pause<i class="material-icons right">pause_circle_outline</i></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try running, it doesn't work. You'll need to use the `innerHTML` property instead, if you want to add html markup.

Comment: my bad :) just copied it from the question